# Why can't I import Crypto after installing pycrypto in Python?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pycrypto

On OSX 10.10, I'm getting 'ImportError: No module named Crypto' in Python 2.7.6 after installing the pycrypto module. I get the error when I run python in the terminal and try `import Crypto`.

I've installed via `sudo pip install pycrypto` and also tried installing from source from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto. According to that site, there's a `python setup.py test` command (which runs fine for me), but it skips modules which aren't available, so I'm not sure if it's actually useful in this case.

The only thing I tried to do was find and compare to other packages in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`... I noticed that the other packages (like Naked, PyYAML, and others) have directories whereas pycrypto just has an 'ASCII text' file (and no directory) according to the `file pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7.egg-info` command. This scenario was after installing from source.

When installing from `pip`, I see that 'pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7.egg-info' shows up as a directory, but there aren't any .py files in there.

I'm new to python and really at a loss. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that you installed it into a different python installation than the python binary you're running?  2.7.6 sounds like the default OS X /usr/bin/python...

Comment: what does `which -a python` output?

Comment: ... and `sudo which -a pip`.

Comment: There's only one version of python and pip

Comment: do you have `/Crypto` directory anywhere ? Does `locate -b "\Crypto"` output anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue was not related to the .egg files - it was the Crypto directory itself.

In my working solution I can't remember whether I used `apt-get` or whether I installed PyCrypto from source, but in the `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` directory I needed to rename the `crypto` directory to `Crypto` and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in CentOS-6.

But I tried
`yum install python-devel` (install python dev didin't work) followed by 
`easy_install pycrypto`.
Now you can import and use without any problem